# filtering data using sql query for show in bar graph

Tags: mysql, sql

here is what is want to do. i want to filter **Job Types** for X axis and **Job count** for the y axis. to x axis i want to get job type with similar name to use only once and for y axis job count of that.
if i consider cutting, then it will be **cutting**(x axis)-**1400**(y axis-sum of 2nd and 5th row). so how to get this using a sql query? my table name is supplier.

[image]

Output will be like:

```
| jobType | totaljobCount |
|---------|---------------|
| CPI     | 302           |
| Cutting | 1400          |
| Ironing | 800           |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY` on the `jobType` and use [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function to aggregate the `jobCount` values.

```
SELECT 
  jobType, SUM(jobCount) AS total_jobCount
FROM supplier
GROUP BY jobType
```

Comment: thanks.. can you tell me if i want to filter these according to month of the job published. how can i do it?

Comment: @PasinduSenarath There is `Month()` function to get the month of a given date. You can then use this in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` appropriately.

Comment: "SELECT jobType,SUM(jobCount) AS jobCount FROM supplier GROUP BY jobType where MONTH(jobPublished)=9 " is this Wrong?

Comment: @PasinduSenarath `WHERE` part comes before `GROUP BY`